# How do I create a temporary table from a query that I am running in SQL?

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I am using MS SQL and I don't have authority to create tables. What I like to do is create a temporary table from a query that I am running (called customer query) and use the temp table and link it to a new query called order query

How do I first create the temp table after I run my customer query, and how can I use that temp table in a second query called order query?

Will the temp table exist and gets updated every time I run my customer query?

Comment: Please show your code and what exactly are you trying to achieve. It looks like CTE/OUTPUT clause could be sufficient.

Comment: Your google search string is `sql server temporary tables`.

Comment: Sounds like you need to push back to your SQL team. Your temp table will only exist for the session and then be gone forever. Hence, *temporary* table. If you need to update the underlying customer tables.you will need access to do so. If you need any of the data to persist outside the session, you will need to update permanent tables.

Comment: below is the main query i am using. i like to take the results from that query and create a temp table. then i would like to link that table to a different query that will give me charges for those customers.                SELECT        Global_customer id, Admission_Time
FROM            dbo.customer table

Comment: Just create a temp table and insert you result there.

Comment: Querying just to use the results to populate the next query is a very programmatic way to accomplish your task, not a good SQLy way to do it. More than likely, you can combine your two queries into one single `JOIN`ed query that will give you the results you need _much_ faster and with just 1 trip to the database instead of 2.

Comment: Temp tables exist for the life of the query/session and then they disappear.  Your statement does not suggest you need a temporary table.  Explain the query you want and people will likely help you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be granted create on tempdb as all temporary tables are actually created in that database.

Seek out your DBA to Grant you the appropriate privilege.

Temp tables only persist as long as you are connected to the scope of the session that created it. You can create a temp table that persists across all sessions but be wary as that be accessed then

An added benefit of your DBA is he or she can explain how to properly create and utilize those tables. :)

Comment: Not him as a user, but whatever webserver process user is running the queries. That user probably should already have permissions to create temp tables. However, for testing, the user that he's running from SSMS (or whatever) to build/run the queries will also need permissions.

Answer (score 1):

See my comment above. No need for a temp table. More than likely, what you need to do is simply a single query.

```
SELECT <colsNeeded>
FROM order  
INNER JOIN customer ON order.<customerID> = customer.<customerID>
WHERE order.X = ???
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like Shawn's answer, but unfortunately I think it's under the assumption that the order query is a simple join. There can be many more things that he needs to do using the temporary table. If it's really needs to be that way, and you have permissions to create a temporary table, I would suggest create dynamic query of the first query and append it to the order query and execute both of them together. That way it'll be in the same session and you'll have access to that table in all the queries inside your order query.